# Display editor for different enums

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following two enums:

```
   public enum Status{
        Active, Finished, Late
    }


   public enum Priority{
       Urgent, Normal,Low, High
   }
```

So essentially i would like to display them in different styles.

For Active status, i would like to have a green label for Late Status I would like to have red label.

Same idea for Priority, for urgent, i would like to display red label and Normal with green label.

Is there an easy way to do this rather than if statements all over the place?

I am using Razor.

Comment: You may want to include what control you are using to display the items. Perhaps the markup used to *currently* display them.

Comment: you can define your custom templates: http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC doesn't do such things automagically but something like this would work:

```
<label class="status-@(Model.Status.ToString().ToLowerInvariant())">...</label>
```

I would prefer to wrap that logic into an helper method such as:

```
public static string CssClass(this Enum e)
{
    string result = e.GetType().Name + "-" + e.ToString();
    return result.ToLowerInvariant();
}
```

and you'd just write:

```
<label class="@Model.Status.CssClass()">...</label>
```

Comment: well there are automagical display and editor templates. hence i asked if there is an easy way .

Comment: this seems like an easy way to me.

Comment: @DarthVader I added a more idiomatic way, perhaps you might like it better.

Comment: Yeah i liked this better. Thanks.